# PHP: preg_replace() with pattern modifier e - strange behaviour in evalution result seems to ignore back references

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following situation: I want to replace links in a string, specifically I want to add a "search engine" link next to it.

Think: Link Title (S), where as S will link to Google with "Link Title" as search term. I've copied a real life example string ($content) in the code so you can reproduce this 1:1 in PHP code.

```
// PCRE case-insensitive, all as a single string, ungreedy and evaluate PHP replace.
$content = '<h3 class="bgg2" style="padding: 4px 0px 4px 5px; font-size: 11px;">» <a href="/forum_detail.html?topic=3456&amp;start=20&amp;post=97145#p97145" class="nub" title="Xenoblade: Japanischer TV-Spot"><b>Xenoblade: Japanischer TV-Spot</b></a></h3>';

$replace = preg_replace('/(<a.*>)(.*)<\/a>/isUe', ('"\1\2</a>&nbsp;(<a href=\"http://www.google.com/search?q=' . strip_tags(strtoupper('blah\2')) . '\">S</a>)"'), $content);

print($replace);
```

Output (incorrect):
Xenoblade: Japanischer TV-Spot (S) -> when you look at the HTML it looks like this:

`<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=BLAH%3Cb%3EXenoblade:%20Japanischer%20TV-Spot%3C/b%3E">S</a>`

**The strtoupper() did get the literal string blah -> BLAH but not the \2 back reference from the regular expression?**

It looks like the \2 back referenced string is used BEFORE `strtoupper()` or `strip_tags()` functions are executed - some kind of timing of evaluation versus functions in PHP perhaps?

Does anybody know how to explain this bevhaviour?

--

I've developed a workaround using `preg_replace_callback`, still I'm puzzled about why the above code doesn't work as I expected.

For reference to see what I want to achive:

**Solution**

```
// I have to use PHP < 5.0 so create_function() will do the job.
$replace = preg_replace_callback('/(<a.*>)(.*)<\/a>/isU',
create_function('$matches', 'return $matches[1] . $matches[2] . \'</a>&nbsp;(<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=\' . strip_tags(strtoupper($matches[2])) . \'">S</a>)\';'),
$content);

print($replace);
```

Output (correct):
Xenoblade: Japanischer TV-Spot (S) -> when you look at the HTML it looks like this:

`<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=XENOBLADE:%20JAPANISCHER%20TV-SPOT">S</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
'"\1\2</a>&nbsp;(<a href=\"http://www.google.com/search?q=' . strip_tags(strtoupper('blah\2')) . '\">S</a>)"'
```

to

```
'"\1\2</a>&nbsp;(<a href=\"http://www.google.com/search?q=" . strip_tags(strtoupper(\'blah\2\')) . "\">S</a>)"'
```

The `strip_tags()` function needs to be a part of the replacement string so it doesn't get evaluated before it gets passed to `preg_replace()`.

Comment: I've tested this and confirmed it as an excellent solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your mixing up a few things. In your first to try you called `strtoupper()`, which works on the passed string. It will take the string `'blah\2'` and turn it into `'BLAH\2'`. It's not working on the result, but on your replacement pattern. It's as if you wrote...

```
'"\1\2</a>&nbsp;(<a href=\"http://www.google.com/search?q='  
 . strip_tags('BLAH\2') . '\">S</a>)"'
```

as replacement pattern.